# Fedora 36 internet speed is very slow

Tags: fedora, wifi, surface

I installed Fedora 36 on a Microsoft surface 3 (Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz,Intel® Iris® Plus Graphics) laptop and while everything works well, internet speed got dramatically reduced. While on my android phone, internet speed is around 30 mbps ( as my internet subscription plan), on Fedora its barely 9 Mbps. Disabling IPV6 didn't help the situation. Searching online, some says its due to Microsoft's poor choice of WiFi chip-set ( i.e Marvell AVASTAR Wireless AC Network Adapter ) but some other resource mention its Fedora related problem. I was wondering if I should switch back to windows 11 to solve this problem or there are solution to make Fedora work on Surface pro 3.

Comment: Does this help? https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-fix-surface-pro-3-wifi-issues/2273

Comment: @mattdm, unfortunately it didn't help. I just switched back to windows and used WSL to get Linux on windows. It seems pretty efficient as well.

Comment: I am having the same problem on spectre x360 gemcut